# CordovaError: Some of requirements check failed

Tags: cordova, npm

I've moved to NodeJs 5.0 and I've faced a problem with running cordova properly.

```
> cordova -v
5.3.3
```

I try to check with: cordova requirements -d

```
Checking requirements for android platform
Checking requirements for ios platform

Requirements check results for android:
Check failed for android due to CordovaError: Failed to check requirements for android platform. check_reqs module is missing for platform. Skipping it...

Requirements check results for ios:
Check failed for ios due to CordovaError: Failed to check requirements for ios platform. check_reqs module is missing for platform. Skipping it...
CordovaError: Some of requirements check failed
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/cli.js:300:41
    at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:557:44
    at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at doNTCallback0 (node.js:428:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:357:13)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:459:11)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
```

**Update:** 11/7/2015

Good news. Today cordova tools is released to 5.4.0 and issues with using Node 4 & 5 and npm 3 was fixed.

```
npm install -g cordova
```

Comment: node 5 includes NPM 3, that has issues with cordova. It's been fixed and will be released probably next week, but in the meantime you have to use node 4

Comment: put the update as answer so more people can see it

Answer (score -4):

**Update:** 11/7/2015

Good news. Today cordova tools is released to 5.4.0 and issues with using Node 4 & 5 and npm 3 was fixed.

```
npm install -g cordova
```